# How to capture last 4 characters from NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsstring, nsrange

I am accepting an `NSString` of random `size` from a `UITextField` and passing it over to a method that I am creating that will capture only the last 4 characters entered in the `string`.

I have looked through `NSString` Class Reference library and the only real option I have found that looks like it will do what I want it to is

```
- (void)getCharacters:(unichar *)buffer range:(NSRange)aRange
```

I have used this once before but with static parameters 'that do not change', But for this implementation I am wanting to use non static parameters that change depending on the size of the string coming in.

So far this is the method I have created which is being passed a `NSString` from an IBAction else where.

```
- (void)padString:(NSString *)funcString
{

    NSString *myFormattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%04d",[funcString intValue]]; // if less than 4 then pad string
    //   NSLog(@"my formatedstring = %@", myFormattedString);

    int stringLength = [myFormattedString length]; // captures length of string maybe I can use this on NSRange?


    //NSRange MyOneRange = {0, 1}; //<<-------- should I use this? if so how?

}
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use the substringFromIndex method,

**OBJ-C:**

```
NSString *trimmedString=[string substringFromIndex:MAX((int)[string length]-4, 0)]; //in case string is less than 4 characters long.
```

**SWIFT:**

```
let trimmedString: String = (s as NSString).substringFromIndex(max(s.length-4,0))
```

Comment: that gives me a warning saying (instance method subStringFromIndex not found type defaults to 'id')

Comment: Ah, its **substringFromIndex** not **subStringFromIndex**, case sensitive :) thanks alot Kingofbliss

Comment: Actually, you should probably protects yourself by using: `NSString *trimmedString=[string substringFromIndex:MAX((int)[string length]-4, 0)];` in case **string** is less than **4** characters long.

Comment: Some loose thoughts: 1.) do not call [substringFromIndex:] unless necessary, 2.) NSString [length] is declared as @property so use the dot notation, 3.) Type-emphasized pointer style forever! ;)
`NSString* trimmedString = string.length > 4 ? [string substringFromIndex:(string.length - 4)] : string;`

Answer (score 10):

Try This,

```
NSString *lastFourChar = [yourNewString substringFromIndex:[yourNewString length] - 4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this function in Swift 5:

```
func subString(from myString: NSString, length: Int) {
    let myNSRange = NSRange(location: myString.length - length, length: length)
    print(myString.substring(with: myNSRange))
}
subString(from: "Menaim solved the issue", length: 4) // Output: ssue
```