# NSMutableString check last and second last character

Tags: iphone, nsmutablestring

I have a `NSMutableString`. I need to check whether the last character is @":" or last two characters are @": "

How to do that?

Comment: I guess that a look at `NSString` class reference could help. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: Try this link may be help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591538/how-to-capture-last-4-characters-from-nsstring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `hasSuffix:` method of `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

Identifies *last char*:

```
NSString *lastChar = [yourstr substringFromIndex: [yourstr length] - 1];
```

---

Identifies *last two chars*:

```
NSString *lastTwoChar = [yourstr substringFromIndex: [yourstr length] - 2];
```